# How to access class variable inside a vector iterator?

Tags: c++, c++98

I'd like to access a public variable of a class instance, where the instances are kept in a vector of the class type. I have to run through all elements of vector using an iterator, but it confuses me as to how I get the variables with the iterator present. I'm using C++98.

source.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Rectangle.h" 

using namespace std;

int main() {    
    int len = 2, hen = 5;   
    int len2 = 4, hen2 = 10;

    Rectangle rect1(len, hen);  
    Rectangle rect2(len2, hen2);        
    vector<Rectangle> Rects;
    Rects.push_back(rect1);
    Rects.push_back(rect2);

    for (std::vector<Rectangle>::iterator it = Rects.begin(); it != Rects.end(); ++it) {        
       //how to access length and height here?  
    }

    system("pause");    
    return 0; 
}
```

Rectangle.h:

```
#pragma once
class Rectangle
{
private:        

public:
    int length;
    int height;

    Rectangle(int& length, int& height);
    ~Rectangle();
};
```

Rectangle.cpp:

```
#include "Rectangle.h"

Rectangle::Rectangle(int& length, int& height) 
    : length(length), height(height)
{ }

Rectangle::~Rectangle() {}
```

Comment: Iterators behave much like pointers, so `it->length` and `(*it).length` will both do what you want (prefer the former in all cases).

Comment: just to clarify: there is no value **inside** the iterator. A better way to think of it is iterators being fancy pointers into a container. The elements are in the container and the iterator just points to them (assuming its a valid iterator)

Comment: Any particular reason, you are using a 20 year old standard?

Comment: @bitmask You mean c++98? I'm working on a microcontrollers. Not all compilers support c++11 or above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the rectangle to vector first, dereference iterator and access the elements.

```
int main() {    
    int len = 2, hen = 5;   
    int len2 = 4, hen2 = 10;

    Rectangle rect1(len, hen);  
    Rectangle rect2(len2, hen2);        
    vector<Rectangle> Rects;
    Rects.push_back(rect1);
    Rects.push_back(rect2);

    for (std::vector<Rectangle>::iterator it = Rects.begin(); it != Rects.end(); ++it) {        
       std::cout << "length " <<(*it).length<<std::endl;
       std::cout << "height " <<(*it).height<<std::endl;
    }

    system("pause");    
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Just for completeness, another way of dereferencing a pointer (iterator) to a class and accessing a member of it is to use the arrow operator `->`, which combines the dereference `*` and member access `.` operators. Thus, `it->length` and `it->height` would work as well.